# Azure failovergroup and database deletion?

Tags: azure, failover

I am test my failover group for Azure SQL. Not sure if i am  missing something obvious.

This is the scenario I am testing

I have a failovergroup configured on SRV1 with grace period 1hr, the primary db is DB1 and the secondary is in a different region and is DB2.

I have tested with the Failover option in Azure and that works. So now the Primary is DB2.
I set the Primary back to DB1.

Now i went to SSMS and deleted DB1.
I would have expected that the secondary would become the Primary , but this is not the case . Even after 1hr the secondary did not become the primary .

Is there something that i am not doing correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you delete the primary database from Azure portal, the secondary will just be deleted. As you actively delete the DB, It will not be considered as a failover action/case

What exactly did you delete though?

Comment: So what i did is create a failover , with primary and secondary sql server and database. I then went and deleted the primary database. I would of thought there would be something in the background that polls for the existence of the primary and if not swap to the secondary.

Comment: Also if we have a primary and secondary, lets say there is a power outage and it swaps to the secondary. Now data is being added to the secondary database. If the outage takes lets say 2 hrs , when its back up what happens , does the primary that was down now become the primary ? What about the data that was added to the secondary , it wont be in the primary or do they sync it ? How does that all work ?

Comment: If you inititated a failover event - or the original primary goes down - The secondary will be the new primary. Dont think of the original primary as the primary anymore. Once the failed DB returns, it becomes secondary and start to automatically replicate from the new primary

Comment: and how long can i assume that when the old primary that went down will be ready to use again ?

Comment: As soon as the db synchronization is completed. Depends on the delta/difference between the dbs during the time they are down

Comment: (Can check inside Azure - Status should be "Readable")
https://imgur.com/a/7S45M5D

Comment: Ok so when it comes back up .. its not readable until the status is set .? Would you know what it is before it is readable , i mean while it is coming up to full syncing with secondary ?

Comment: Also do i need to do a failover if i want the original primary back as primary ?

Comment: The failover cluster as a whole will be "always" readable. As all requests shall be directed to the new primary instance when the old primary fail. Once the old primary (now becomes secondary) finish sync, it will be readable by itself too (helpful to offload part of the read operation from the primary DB) (Please start another question as the comment section is rather long and unfocused)